# Li-po charger circuit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm trying to design a circuit that provides Li-po battery power to a rail that (when the device is stationary) is powered by an AC/DC converter and accepts 9-20 V. The problem is that the rail and the load can't be separated and can only be accessed at point B1.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. When connected to AC/DC converter (at B1) the entire battery circuit should be cut off.
2. Use the device while charging.

The batteries have separate charging circuitry for backup, in case one fails.

[image]

Could you give me some pointers, or possible improvements? Not sure about the [MC34673](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC34673.pdf) either, I was thinking if the [MCP73871](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) would be a better choice (regarding usage during charging).

Comment: Is it just my old eyes or is that schematic really hard to read due to the black background choice?

Comment: And what is the question you ask after providing the background info?

Comment: Pointers, or possible improvements. Not sure about the MC34673 either, was thinking if the  MCP73871 would be a better choice (regarding usage during charging)?

Comment: Welcome! Please change the background color to white for readability. Possibly even larger font as well.

Comment: Thank you, done and done.

Comment: What's the purpose of Q1?

Comment: To cut off the entire charging circuitry when AC/DC is connected.

Comment: Q1's body diode is forward biased, so as long as the boost regulator (U3) operates the Q2 will be on (assuming a nonzero load current). Even if we assume the Q2 is off, when a high enough voltage is applied across `B1` and `GND-D` the Q2 will turn on because its source pin will see B1 voltage whilst the gate is grounded, making the Vgs negative. So, if an external voltage is applied whilst the boost regulator is running, something terrible may happen.

Comment: The usual KISS way is to put a diode (schottky for low forward voltage) in series with the battery, and make sure the DC supply exceeds the battery voltage, thus cutting off the diode.

Comment: You could always make the boost converter into a buck/boost and combine all power sources with diodes on the input

Comment: Please, please!  Change your schematic to have completely black components and wires on a full white background!.  It is far too difficult to read!

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFET gate is always shorted to the source: -

[image]

So, I'm unsure what you actually want to happen. There may be other problems but this stuck out.

Comment: You are right, see that now. Well, when connected to AC/DC (at B1) the entire battery circuit should be cut off.

Comment: Connecting AC at B1 will be a problem because of the MOSFET body diode.

Comment: @Finbarr I think the OP meant AC/DC converter.

Comment: Correct, AC/DC converter

Comment: OK, but the body diode is still going to be a problem with 9V DC connected.

Comment: @Finbarr what if I add another schottky in front of D4?

Comment: @xand3r you made an edit to my answer but, I can't tell what that edit was. Please explain.

Comment: @Andyaka I was told to remove my edit, so no change to your answer. I instead posted another answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution?

VIN1=ON  | VIN2=OFF : batteries cut off (charging), device powered from VIN1
VIN1=OFF | VIN2=OFF : device powered from batteries

Disable access to VIN2.

[image]

**Updated circuit**

[image]

Comment: Still the same problem if you have less than 12V applied - the MOSFET body diode will be forward biased and your batteries will power the load with 12V. The MOSFET isn't actually doing any switching at all.

Comment: @Finbarr Yes you are right (again), How about If I move the MOSFET where R7 is that is right in front of the batteries and switch places of the diodes, one just on the outlet of the booster right after C6?

Comment: A better option would be to use a boost converter chip with an enable input and use that to switch it off when external power is supplied.

Comment: @Finbarr Would you care to explain why? I mean placing the MOSFET in front of the LM2577 is essentially doing the same thing as an enable pin would?

Comment: Because you'd no longer need the MOSFET

Comment: @Finbarr Yes, I understand that, but why is it better?